# Insert data into specific table with jQuery laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, html-table

I've 2 tables, and I'm to trying pass table value from controller into specific table, but data show inside both table.

//Controller

```
public function user_ajukan_uji_ajax(Request $request)
{
            $request->ajax();        
            $output="";
            $user=DB::table('user')->where('id','like','%'.$request->search.'%')->get();
            foreach ($user as $key => $user) 
            {
                $output.='<tr>'.
                         '<td>'.$user->id.'</td>'.
                         '<td>'.$user->nama_user.'</td>'.
                         '<td>'.$user->telp_user.'</td>'.
                         '<td>'.$user->email_user.'</td>'.
                         '<td>'.$user->kategori_user.'</td>'.
                         '<td>'.$user->created_at.'</td>'.
                         '</tr>';
            } 
        return response($output); 
}
```

//script for pass value into table

```
 <script >
            $('#search').on('keyup',function(){
            $value=$(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    'type' : 'get',
                    'url' : '{{URL::to('ajax-request-ajukan-uji')}}',
                    'data' : {'search' : $value},
                    success : function(data){
                        $('tbody').html(data); 
                        }
            });
       });
    </script>
```

//my table that I want to pass the value into it

```
<table id="data_tampil_pengguna_ajukan_uji" class="table table-responsive display" data-form="data_pengguna" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr class="danger">
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>Nomor Telepon</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Kategori</th>
                <th>Tanggal Bergabung</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Please help me.. every answer is very appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, my problem solved.. here the solution

//add tbody id inside the table

```
<table id="data_tampil_pengguna_ajukan_uji" class="table table-responsive display" data-form="data_pengguna" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr class="danger">
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>Nomor Telepon</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Kategori</th>
                <th>Tanggal Bergabung</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <tbody id="user_show"></tbody>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

//in the script, pass value into tbody id

```
<script >
        $('#search').on('keyup',function(){
            $value=$(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        'type' : 'get',
                        'url' : '{{URL::to('ajax-request-ajukan-uji')}}',
                        'data' : {'search' : $value},
                        success : function(data){
                        $('#user_show').html(data); 
                        }
               });
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:

```
foreach ($user as $key => $user) {
```

here you are storing the data in `$user` and than again using a looping variable as `$user` which is wrong.

Comment: thank you for your answered, my problem is to pass the value into one table, and it has been solved. :)